# Invoke scrapy script from PHP/HTML or webserver

Tags: php, python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapyd

I have a scrapy script which will run multiple spiders. I want to crawl the single spider or run the multiple spider script from PHP/HTML code. Is that possible? If so, how?

Comment: Does [this documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script) answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in PHP:

Add this line in your python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Make the script executable:

```
chmod +x myscript.py
```

Execute the file using something like this:

```
<?php 

$command = escapeshellcmd('/home/myscript.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Rahul